# Are there benefits to keeping the Google Sign-In account connected after Firebase Auth via GSI has been signed in?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

When signing-in via Firebase Auth with the "google.com" provider, are there any benefits to keeping the underlying Google Account connected?

All the samples I've seen do leave it connected, but I've come across the situation where I'm better off disconnecting the Google Account as soon as I have signed into Firebase via `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(result.getIdToken(), null))` instead of leaving it connected ("signed in"). It's even possible to disconnect before calling `signInWithCredential`, since the idToken is still valid for a certain amount of time.

Doing this doesn't seem to have any negative side effects. This is what I'm doing:

```
GoogleSignInClient client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleSignInOptions);
client.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
    @Override public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount result = task.getResult();

            // Disconnect from Google Account
            GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleSignInOptions).signOut();

            if (result != null) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(result.getIdToken(), null)).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        // but I might as well disconnect here
                        //GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleSignInOptions).signOut();

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                            // OK, user is signed in

                            //...
```